# How can I correctly set the required HTML attribute to an input tag into a TymeLeaf page?

Tags: html, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

I am pretty new in Spring MVC and absolutly new in **ThymeLeaf**.

So I am working on a web application that use **TymeLeaf** as view technology and I have to use this **Jquery Validation Plugin**: http://jqueryvalidation.org/

So I have used it in the past into JSP pages.

As shown in the documentation: http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/

I have to add the **required** attribute to my input tag that have to be fill by the user, something like this:

```
<input id="cemail" type="email" name="email" required>
```

I tryied to do this thing into my **TymeLeaf** HTML page, in this way:

```
<input id="nome" name="nome" type="text" th:value="*{nome}" required></input>
```

But the problem is now I obtain this error message in the stacktrace console and the page is not renderd:

```
15:36:47,180 ERROR [org.thymeleaf.templateparser.ErrorHandler] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-3) [THYMELEAF][http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-3] Fatal error during parsing: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 88; columnNumber: 78; Attribute name "required" associated with an element type "input" must be followed by the ' = ' character.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:196)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:175)
```

Why? What is wrong? How can I correctly set the **required** HTML attribute to an input tag declated into a **ThymeLeaf** page?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The correct way to declare the **required** attribute in HTML5 with **thymeleaf** is `th:required="required"`.

Try:

```
<input id="nome" name="nome" type="text" th:value="*{nome}" th:required="required"></input>
```

Comment: should anyone need it: `th:required="${is_required} ? 'required' : null"`

Answer (score 1):

Use it:

```
<input id="cemail" type="email" name="email" required="true" />
```

> The Thymeleaf Standard Dialect can process templates in any mode, but
>   is especially suited for web-oriented template modes (XHTML and HTML5
>   ones). Besides HTML5, it specifically supports and validates the
>   following XHTML specifications: XHTML 1.0 Transitional, XHTML 1.0
>   Strict, XHTML 1.0 Frameset, and XHTML 1.1.

See More On : http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#what-is-thymeleaf